# How to configure selenium for python in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, selenium

I know we have to use pip install command for selenium installation. But I want to know how eclipse add those package files in python project. Because in java we add jar files manually in build path. How configuration differs for java and python in eclipse?

Comment: Not a SO question as such. Please check https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/pydev-python-ide-eclipse and http://www.pydev.org/manual_101_root.html

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps to add libraries to Eclipse:

- Go to Properties of PyDev project parent folder and select **PyDev -
  PYTHONPATH**
- Navigate to **External Libraries** tab
- Click on **Add source folder** button and add path

Here you go, libraries are now added to Eclipse.

Selenium libraries are present in the below path in my laptop.

> C:\Users\*****\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages